Sqlite3 JS update variable number of fields
I am working on a sqlite3 database. I want to create a wrapper function for updating the entries of a table taking in the rowid (primary key) and an update object.
const testUpdate = {
    isFavorite : true,
    rating : 4,
}

const updateMovie = function(id, update) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const sql = 'UPDATE films SET isFavorite = ?, rating = ? WHERE id = ?';
        db.run(sql, update.isFavorite, update.rating, id, (err, rows) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}

Using ? allows sanitizing against SQL injection and other attacks so I know I should not use string interpolation for the SQL (which would solve all my problems easily) but what if I wanted my update object to have a variable number of attributes (for example in one case I would want to update isFavorite, rating and watchDate and in another case I would want to update just isFavorite)?
Two solutions come to my mind:

Read the entry from the DB and update all the values using the old values as default ones.
Perform multiple updates conditionally for each field of the object if defined. (This should probably done inside a transaction).

How should I go about this?



id
title
isFavorite
rating
watchDate
userId




2
21 Grams
1
4
2024-03-17
1


3
Star Wars
0
NULL
NULL
1


4
Matrix
0
NULL
NULL
2


5
Shrek
0
3
2024-03-21
2




This is relatively simple to do.
First, you want to figure out all of the keys you are updating:
let keys = Object.keys(update)

First, loop through each key to ensure it is in a list of valid keys:

const validKeys = ["title","isFavorite","rating","watchDate","userId"];
keys = keys.filter(key => validKeys.indexOf(key) != -1);

Then, loop through each key to build your set string (x = ?, y = ?, z = ?)
const setStr = keys.map(key=> `${key} = ?`).join(', ');

Then, get all the values that you want to update your keys to:
const values = keys.map(key=> update[key]);

Because the values stand in for all the ?s, you need to add the final value for the id (WHERE id = ?)
values.push(id);

Then you can just run your sql statement with the values passed.
db.run(`UPDATE films SET ${setStr} WHERE id = ?`, values, (err, rows)=>{
    if(err) return console.error(err)
    console.log(rows);
});


Note: where you did (sql, update.isFavorite, update.rating, id,..., it should be sql, [update.isFavorite, update.rating, id],... The second parameter of db.run is a list.


Regarding the Note actually db.run works with either the list or a variable number of arguments so enclosing the parameters in a list is optional

This uses string interpolation. I am not an expert on SQL injection but I am not sanitizing the key values with this approach and that sould make it insecure

An attacker could send an updateObject = {DROP: "TABLE FILMS"} or something like that...

@UmbertoFontanazza no.... the only thing that is interpolated are the Key values. Unless you are passing const testUpdate = { "malicious SQL here": 1 }  it will work

No user-entered things can make it inject sql.... because only the keys are interpolated only the keys can inject sql. I am going to guess that the keys are not user-made but exist only on your server. If only you can change the keys by modifying the code directly, you are safe from injection

In my case the keys are parsed from the body of a POST request so I cannot assume that.

ok.... then its just an easy check to ensure that they are secure... check the updated code

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
